# WordPress Contact Form Plugin for Arabic

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have tried many WordPress contact form plugins (free versions) but none of them is fulfilling my requirements, please advise any plugin for Arabic web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 plugin available in wordpress for Arabic WeB Site. download link available (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Comment: i tried this ! this functionality is not available in Free Version

Comment: This Contact Form7 Plugin is Free version  please add and install in wordpress site then after go on the Add new Button then after are u see the option language choose..